# Lead to Order Table design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a User table having following fields:

```
id, name, phone, email
```

and an Order table:

```
id, order_name, order_desc, user_id (fk to User)
```

and a Lead table:

```
id, lead_desc, user_id (fk to User), lead_status
```

Now, I want to know for each lead (once the lead_status become closed), which order is created from this lead or no order is created from this lead. I am planning to have an order_id (with null=True) foreign key in Lead table to keep this mapping. But since Order table already have a user_id, it doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Is there a better way to do it? I am using Mysql.

Comment: Is the `user_id` in the `Order` entry and the corresponding `Lead` entry always the same `User`?

Comment: @Marco Yes. It will be same.

Answer (score 0):

One of the of goals of a relational database is to eliminate double storage of data. If you can find the right `User` for the `Lead` through the `Order` then you can leave out the reference in one of the tables (they are always the same as you mentioned in a comment). Keeping it in both tables makes your application more complicated.

Comment: I understand that but `Lead` record is created first and then `Order` is created. Also, `Order` can be created independently.

Comment: From your question there is no real indication of the use of `Lead`. From your last remark I make up that there need not be a 'link' all the time between a `Lead` and an `Order`. In that case you need to keep the `user_id` in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding I have given the following points, it may change as per your requirements.

**Business Rule:**

1. Each user can have more than one Lead inquires.
2. Each Lead must be belongs to at least one User.
3. Each Lead can contain one or more Products/Services.
4. Each Product/Service can belongs to one or more Lead.
5. A User can place more than one Order.
6. Each Order must belongs to one User.
7. Each Order can contain one or more Products/Services.
8. Each Product/Service may belongs to more than Order.
9. Each Order must contain to atleast one Lead.
10. Each Lead may belongs to atleast one Order.

**Data Model:**

For the above mentioned business rules, the **logical data model** may look like as follows:

[image: User-Lead-Order Logical Data Model]

In my opinion, if you need to capture and report `key performance indicators (KPI)` of the business, you need to clearly define the relationship between the `Lead` and `Order`. Usually, the business flow will be, first `Lead` created and `Lead` may / may not converted into an `Order`, in such cases, you can store the `Lead_ID` in `Order` table, so that all the `Order` will have `Lead_ID` and note that, reverse it may not possible, since all leads may not converted into `Order`.

Also, there is no clarity that, whether all the order must comes only through leads. Before starting anything, make sure to clearly define the [entities](http://www.rathishkumar.in/2015/12/entities.html). I suggest you to always start with **[conceptual data model](http://www.rathishkumar.in/2015/12/conceptual-data-model.html)** to **physical table design**. As per your requirement, the design may change. I hope this answer will help you, Thanks.